# floating point division by zero

Tags: ruby

I was expecting the following code to throw an error but instead it returns `NaN`. is this behavior described anywhere? why is it different from integer division by zero?

```
0.0 / 0.0 # => NaN
```

EDIT: I need to return zero in this case so I was going to

```
(x / y rescue 0)
```

but this did not work. how to do it?

Comment: Duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726615/why-in-ruby-0-0-0-3-0-0-and-3-0-behave-differently

Comment: `0/0` is an indeterminate form so it's accuarate from ruby to return `NaN` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res = x/y
res = 0 unless res.finite?
```

`finite?` returns true if a float is a valid floating point number ( not infinite, and nan? is false).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
x == 0 and y == 0 ? 0 : x/y
```

or

```
x.nonzero? || y.nonzero? ? x/y : 0
```

Comment: yes, definitely, thank you. i was looking for a way to make sure my (arbitrary) expression does not evaluate to `NaN`. is there a check for `NaN` in ruby?

Comment: @akonsu There is a `.nan?` method but it doesn't work for integers, only for floats

Comment: I am curious too. +1 to even out.